# Dynamic Object Creation with RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I would like to make a project with RMI, but I would like to know this. Is it possible to create new remote objects on demand while the server is operating? If so, is there anything special needed?

Comment: Yes. Any object you want return to the clines must implement the Remote interface and the implement an interface that the client understands (ie, you should have provided a remote interface library that the client interacts with)

Comment: I know about the `Remote` interface, but can I create remote objects on the fly? Such as when a user is created, can I create a `User` remote object on the fly?

Comment: Yes. You will still need an exported object that the client can connect to, but then that object can create more objects and return them to client as you want

Comment: Well, then post that as an answer and I'll accept it. How does this work with my more recent question of JDO and RMI?

Comment: I not think it will make much difference, so long as you have a client interface that interact with th objects created on the server

Comment: I'm not so sure. JDO only stores the data, and when you retrieve an object, wouldn't a new copy be created?

Comment: It would depend oh which side of fence the responsibility lay. I'd imagine you would simply expose a simple interface in the kinet and then generate the JDO implementation on the server. It would then be up to the server to manage these instances. But generally speaking, I'd imagine each client would get there own copy. When it comes time to write it, the server would need to decide what to do about out of date objects

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not quite. The remote object must implement an interface *that extends Remote.*

Comment: @ejp Implements, extends, working in the same direction :P

Comment: @tbodt Updated with answer, let me know if I've missed anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer The wording in your answer is correct. The wording in your comment above is not. The wording in the comment implies that the application interface doesn't need to extend `Remote.` 'And then' doesn't mean 'extends Remote'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, yes.

There are some caverts though.

1. The object begin returned to the client must implement a interface that the client has access to
2. The object begin returned must implement the Remote interface (or implement an interface that extends from Remote)

Basically, the object the is "exported" to the RMI server would act as a factory that the client would be able to call and it would then create what ever new remote objects it required.